# Ubuntu Core & Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W

Tags: boot, sd-card, ubuntu, bootloader, pi-zero-w-2

I'm trying to run Ubuntu Core 20 on Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W.

According to [Install Ubuntu on RPi](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) this should work without a problem when using the 32bit version. Or with 64bit version using following procedure [Ubuntu Server support for Zero 2 W](https://ubuntu.com/blog/raspberry-pi-zero-2-w-with-ubuntu-server-support-is-here).

I tried both options but my RPi Zero 2 W refuses to bootup -> according to [LED code](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern) 7x blinks this means it's unable to find `kernel.img`.

Can I ask if someone has some idea or procedure on how to fix this?

***Boot SD Card structure:***

```
Folder PATH listing for volume ubuntu-seed
Volume serial number is 3227-A7E8
F:.
├───uboot
│   └───ubuntu
├───snaps
├───overlays
├───.disk
└───systems
    └───20210630
        ├───assertions
        ├───snaps
        └───kernel
            └───dtbs
                ├───broadcom
                └───overlays
PS F:\> ls


    Directory: F:\


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM                uboot
d-----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM                snaps
d-----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM                overlays
d-----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM                .disk
d-----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM                systems
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM         791356 start4cd.elf
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM           3176 fixup4cd.dat
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM          47761 bcm2711-rpi-400.dtb
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM          19840 bcm2837-rpi-cm3-io3.dtb
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM            733 config.txt
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM           5429 fixup4.dat
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM           3176 fixup_cd.dat
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM          20933 bcm2837-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM          20513 bcm2837-rpi-3-b.dtb
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM         556936 uboot_rpi_arm64.bin
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM           8436 fixup4x.dat
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM           8440 fixup4db.dat
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM          47733 bcm2711-rpi-cm4.dtb
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM           4638 boot.scr
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM           7301 fixup.dat
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM          47600 bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM        2940128 start.elf
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM         791356 start_cd.elf
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM          71191 psplash.img
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM         514944 uboot_rpi_3.bin
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM        4788712 start_db.elf
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM          26277 bcm2710-rpi-cm3.dtb
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM        3716808 start4db.elf
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM            117 cmdline.txt
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM          10288 fixup_db.dat
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM          28587 bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM          20064 bcm2837-rpi-3-a-plus.dtb
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM        3698952 start_x.elf
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM          10288 fixup_x.dat
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM        2975368 start4x.elf
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM          52456 bootcode.bin
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM          27968 bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM          26470 bcm2710-rpi-2-b.dtb
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM         570336 uboot_rpi_4.bin
-a----         6/30/2021  12:18 PM        2215776 start4.elf
-a----          1/1/2022   7:45 PM          27137 bcm2710-rpi-zero-2.dtb
```

```
Folder PATH listing for volume ubuntu-boot
Volume serial number is 25E6-AC61
E:.
├───uboot
│   └───ubuntu
│       ├───pi-kernel_302.snap
│       │   └───dtbs
│       │       ├───broadcom
│       │       └───overlays
│       ├───pi-kernel_376.snap
│       │   └───dtbs
│       │       ├───broadcom
│       │       └───overlays
│       └───pi-kernel_377.snap
│           └───dtbs
│               ├───broadcom
│               └───overlays
└───device
```

Comment: does the image boot successfully on your pi3, pi4 or pi400 (you didn't mention which one you have)?

Comment: @Bravo img works on RPi4B without a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved on [AskUbuntu Stack - Ubuntu Core & Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384864/ubuntu-core-raspberry-pi-zero-2-w/)

**Solution** (taken from https://qengineering.eu/install-64-os-on-raspberry-pi-zero-2.html)

- created `rpi-zero-2-w.dtb` from `bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb` file (copy)
- modified `config` with

```
[pi0]
kernel=uboot_rpi_3.bin
```

- RPi Zero 2 W is now booting OK